# TMUX NewSession problem with php page

Tags: command-line, scripts, apache2, php, tmux

I have a problem,
I have a garry's mod server wich i start with this command:

```
./gmodserver start
```

In user **gmodserver**

I'm trying to make a script wich i can execute with a php page for reboot my gmod server. The script:

```
screen -dmS test
screen -S test -X stuff 'sudo su - gmodserver\n'
screen -S test -X stuff 'sleep 1\n'
screen -S test -X stuff 'echo "Rebooting ..."\n'
screen -S test -X stuff 'sleep 1\n'
screen -S test -X stuff 'killall -s 9 srcds_linux srcds_run\n'
screen -S test -X stuff './../../../../home/gmodserver/gmodserver start \n'
screen -S test -X stuff 'sleep 5\n'
screen -S test -X stuff 'exit\n'
screen -S test -X stuff 'exit\n'
```

When i execute this script from terminal, there is no problen, my tmux session nicely created with `./gmodserver start`. And the server restart.
Here, if i make a `tmux ls` I see:

```
gmodserver: 1 windows (created Thu Jul 18 18:39:08 2019) [80x22]
```

So here, all is good.
But when i execute the script with php, with:

```
shell_exec('./restart.sh');
```

The server nicely restart, but if I make `tmux ls` i don't see my gmodserver session, so I can't attach it, so I can't do what I wan't to do.

**NOTE:**

- Apache is running on www-data user
- I make no pass for sudo for www-data and gmodserver
- ./gmodserver start, isn't my script, but LinuxGSM script
- PHP Running in 7.2

I hope you can help me, sorry for my english, i'm french, see u :)